# Change scatter plot point colors based on thresholds on x and y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I basically want something similar to the image attached. [image]

I was trying to achieve the same with scatter method of Matplotlib library. Basically I have x and y which are a list of two parameters and a third parameter lets say z which has labels for the corresponding x and y values, all (x,y,z are pandas.series object). What I plan to achieve is to color everything below y_threshold as gray and label it as not significant, everything above y_threshold but greater than x_threshold as red and labelled as up and everything above y_threshold and less than x_threshold as blue and labelled as down all of them in different color.

And also if possible have the labels from z for the top few hits.

I used the Matplotlib but didn't get the desired result. All other solutions using other libraries are also encouraged.

Comment: Can you please provide some (sample) data and the code that you have so far?

Comment: If x and y are stored in numpy arrays (or pandas columns), you can draw this in 3 steps. Like `filter_down = (x < 0) & (y > 3); ax.scatter(x[filter_down], y[filter_down], color='cornflowerblue', label='Down')` etc..  Note that numpy needs the array versio of the boolean `and` operator (`&`).